# How to I determine what a family is when using Benjamini-Hochberg procedure?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

We're doing repeated testing on 10 dependent variables for differences between groups of 5 independent variables.  I'd like to use the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure to control the false discovery rate, but am unsure what to consider a family of tests.  Are all 50 tests a family?  Or are there 10 families each consisting of 5 tests?